# Getting an old build and set up stellar core

Tags: stellar-core

I want to set up old build (not using docker). If I download the source code, how do i build the core from that?
Say I download v10.2.0rc4 from https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/releases.

I want to set this up in ubuntu 16. Any details step I can follow to build the core?

Answer (score 0):

It's all described in the install docs:

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL.md#basic-installation

Comment: The above steps mentioned (in link provided) works for me when I clone the git repository. As per my understanding, when I clone GIT repository, I get the latest build right? My requirement is to build an old version that too from source code & not GIT.

Comment: Checkout your desired version `git checkout tags/v9.2.0` or download it from https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/tags